# GridLayout with different sized Squares not displaying correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to make this GridLayout to display correctly but it's not working for some reason.

This is what I have and what I want it to be:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
GridLayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mCustomView.setLayoutManager(lm);
mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(imagesList);
mCustomView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
```

and this is under **OnCreateViewHolder** in **CustomAdapter**

```
itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
      final GridLayoutManager lm = (GridLayoutManager) ((RecyclerView) parent).getLayoutManager();
      lm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
          @Override
          public int getSpanSize(int position) {
              int mod = position % 4;
              if(mod == 1 || mod == 2)
                  return 1;
              else
                  return 2;
          }
      });
      int pLength = itemView.getWidth();
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams pParams = itemView.getLayoutParams();
      pParams.width = pLength;
      pParams.height = pLength;
      itemView.setLayoutParams(pParams);
      itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
  }
});
```

If there's any doubts regarding the question or if you need more information, I'd be happy to give it :)

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you're not going to be able to get the exact layout you would like.  The diagram you show of how it should be would require a device whose height is 2x its width.  Typical aspect ratios are more like 1.6.  I think what you're seeing is that the smaller panels are being restricted during layout to keep them all on display (and since panel 1 can only be half height, it's limited to half width as well).

Comment: No no no, the problem is that only the first element (position = 0) for some reason is displaying wrong (can be seen in the diagram). It's correctly displaying afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a week of struggle, I found the fix. It's very stupid that I wasted 1 week on something like this, but here it is. Instead of calling the function **setSpanSizeLookup()** in the **OnCreateViewHolder** in **CustomAdapter**, it should be called **when the adapter is called** i.e.

```
GridLayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
lm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        int mod = position % 4;
        if(mod == 1 || mod == 2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }
});
mCustomView.setLayoutManager(lm);
mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(imagesList);
mCustomView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
```

This fixed the bug for some unknown reason.

**NOTE:** Even though, Cole suggested almost the same thing, but it was not in context with the question. He could have answered my question correctly, if he had read my current code first.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,you can use custom view to wrap item view.And in custom view,you should overide `onMeasure` method:

```
@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        // set your width and height 
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

### Another idea

When you create `layoutManager`:

```
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {  
            @Override  
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {  
               if( position % 4 == 1 || position %4 ==2)
                   return 1;
               else
                   return 2;
            }  

  });
```

The manager will auto set width and height for each item so you don't set manualy

Comment: I don't have a fixed width or height. I want it to use all the width available to it as in the GridLayout span.

Comment: Your item's width and height is random?

Comment: It is a GridLayout of 3 columns, so as seen in the question, the first element will take 2 Column Span and the next will take 1 Column Span.

Comment: That's easy.First you can get the GridLayout's width and then set the two children's width in your `RV Adapter`.

Comment: Do you forget `position` = 0 ?

Comment: Didn't you see the question? I'm already doing. And obviously I know that position starts from 0. Again, please see the question before answering the question.

Comment: I'm sorry.I have not thought a lot.